# Create new column of character vectors

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to combine two columns of type "character" into a new column. That is,

```
ColA    ColB    ColC
"A"     "1"     c("A", "1")
"B"     "2"     c("B", "2")
"C"     "3"     c("C", "3")
```

I have tried:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(ColC = list(ColA, ColB))
```

and other variants but this doesn't work. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can user `rowwise`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(ColC = list(c(.)))
```

Or using `pmap`

```
df %>%
  mutate(ColC = pmap(., ~ c(...)))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ColA = c("A", "B", "C"), ColB = 1:3), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple `paste` would do the job in this example

```
df=data.frame(colA=c("A","B","C"), colB=c("1","2","3"))
df$ColC=paste(df$colA, df$colB)
df
  colA colB ColC
1    A    1  A 1
2    B    2  B 2
3    C    3  C 3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use dplyr `df$ColC <- apply(df[,c("ColA", "ColB")], 1, paste, collapse = " ").`